# Designing an amplifier to drive a speaker

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, gain, speakers, breadboard

I am a beginner in designing this circuit, can someone give me a tip on how can I achieve the following specs?

- Variable gain and a maximum gain of 12 dB
- Input impedance greater than 30 kΩ
- Load impedance of 8-16Ω (buzzer will suffice)
- Input signal range 0 – 1 V pk-pk

I will be designing this in TinkerCad.

The components that I  plan to use are:

1. Operational amplifier (LM 741)
2. Rotary potentiometer, 100k ohm
3. Battery 9V (DC power dupply)
4. Buzzer (to act as the speaker)
5. 0.1μF monolithic capacitor
6. Resistors – 10 kΩ, 20 kΩ, 30 kΩ, 47 kΩ
7. Breadboard

Comment: Please don't tell me that you are limited to just four resistor values.... Is it true? And no way with the LM741. You'll need more than 6 V swing, pk to pk, from it and it just won't go there from 9 V.

Comment: You will need external BJTs, too.

Comment: Ah, yes I am just limited to these values :') As it is for my project requirements :')) I think I may have gotten a glimpse at the least

Comment: Then I will post an answer of how it is actually done. You don't need to select it. It's fun and I don't care.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll struggle to get much output power from a 741 - it’s not designed to drive the output current needed for an 8 or 16-ohm load, which could peak at 500mA depending on how it’s driven.  An LM741 will provide 25mA at short circuit, so perhaps 10-15mA into a moderate load, and probably with significant distortion (although if you’re using a buzzer as an output transducer you probably don’t care much about that).  12dB corresponds to a gain of about 15.  I’m not going to give you all the answers here :-). Use the potentiometer just as a voltage divider at the input, and place a capacitor between the input signal and the potentiometer to ensure that there’s no DC going through it.  Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: Ah, I see. Probably one more question would hopefully help me to get started with this, if I directly connect the DC power supply to the positive and negative rail of the breadboard, how am I going to achieve a Vin/2 (meaning +4.5 and -4.5) voltage for the positive and negative power supply of the op amp

Comment: @CassandraJacklya You can't easily create a Vin/2 rail. A resistor divider is fine, if this is just to adjust an input level at low current. But to create a serious mid-level ground return requires a 2-quadrant driver stage -- which is most of the work for another amplifier. And if you go that far, you may as well use a bridge-tied arrangement, instead, and dump the Vin/2 idea.

Answer (score 3):

This will work off of a 9V battery. Probably would be nice to add another pot for the VBE-multiplier. But it isn't in the spec, so I left it out:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWl7R8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above will accept an input that almost meets your specifications. It was designed to actually meet them, but given resistor tolerances and considering it's maximum gain is a little higher, it probably can only be said to handle \$900\:\text{mV}_\text{p-p}\$. The voltage gain is up to 14.8 dB, but can be easily dialed down with the potentiometer you asked for. If backed off to about 12 dB, then it will handle \$1\:\text{V}_\text{p-p}\$ even with the tolerances, I believe. And deliver up to a quarter-watt into the \$16\:\Omega\$ headphone/speaker. (Dissipation in the BJTs is well within their capabilities.)

Reasonably fresh batteries, only, when expecting maximum output!

Comment: I think that the inclusion of R1 & R2 is unnecessary. The biasing created by R4 & R5 is sufficient to put both inputs of the op amp at mid-supply. In fact in a real circuit if R1 & R2 are included then resistor value tolerance will create two slightly different bias voltages, one created by R1 & R2 and a second created by R4 & R5. This will cause a voltage offset at the amplifier's output (junction of R17 & R18). Best to remove R1 & R2 and let C2 charge via R3 to the bias voltage set by R4 & R5. This would also have the benefit of increasing the input impedance.

Comment: @James I think you make a good point. I guess that's what happens when I just pop out a design as fast as I can place parts. I was over-thinking. There's another point, too. And that's given the use of modern 2% or 1% resistor tolerances, I would need to back off a little and probably say this won't handle a full 1 V pk-pk at maximum gain, but perhaps 900 mV pk-pk, just because of that. Thanks for the thoughtful comment. I'll update as you suggested. Thanks, again!

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I'll keep them into consideration :)